Saying kufar in mind
I have got thoughts related to kufar and even I accept it for a in my heart for a while in my mind and heart. Then I reject those thoughts by my heart and soul and make tauba. Please
guide me if it is really a kufar

Prophet peace and blessing be upon him said, his ummah is save from whatever thought comes Their mind as long as , they don't work on it. So as long as you didn't do something about it, you are fine.Just ignore them, the moment you start researching and doing this and that then that's when the problem starts.
Don't open the door for shaytan and do alot of adhkar.
Lastly this is not fatwa place akhi, I don't think anyone of us is capable of giving fatwa. Try islamqa.info or islamweb.net, I believe they already Have answer to this Question. May Allah make it easy for you and easy for us
